# Need help opening the default email client with prefilled fields ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, html-email

I found this code on another site which has the basics in it.  I have made a few changes because there were errors coming up however when I run this code, the variable page is coming up as null and I'm not sure why. After I get the basics I would build off on it but I need this to work first.

ViewPage:

```
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Email" name="Email" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Button1_Click", "Strategy", new {id = Model.StrategyId})'">Email</button>
```

Code Behind:

```
        public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string email = "abc@abc.com";
        var page = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "mailto", "parent.location='mailto:" + email + "'", true);
    }
```

MVC Code I also tried...The only issue with this code is that I wont have access to all the users passwords and I don't just want to send it via Outlook because not everyone uses Outlook. Ideally it should open the default email for the user to send.

```
 MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();


    //    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(senderID);
    //      mailMessage.Subject = messageSubject;

    //      mailMessage.Body = Convert.ToString(TempData["message"]);
    //      mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    //      //mailMessage.Body = messageBody;

    //      if (strat.FollowUpDate == null)
    //      {
    //          mailMessage.Body = messageBody + "<br/><br/>" + "<b>Create Date: </b>" + strat.CreateDate.ToString("MM/dd/yy") + "<br/>" + "<b>Updated: </b>" + strat.Updated + "<br/>" + "<b>Customer: </b>" + strat.Customer + "<br/>" + "<b>End Product: </b>" + strat.EndProduct + "<br/>" + "<b>OSR: </b>" + strat.OSR + "<br/>" + "<b>Principal: </b>" + strat.Principal + "<br/>" + "<b>Product: </b>" + strat.Product + "<br/>" + "<b>Followup Date: </b>" + "<br/>" + "<b>Value: </b>" + strat.Value + "<br/>" + "<b>Status: </b>" + strat.Status + "<br/>" + "<b>Next Action: </b>" + strat.NextAction + "<br/>" + "<b>Latest Comments: </b>" + strat.ManagerComment + "<br/>" + "<b>History: </b>" + strat.History + "<br/>" + "<b>Group: </b>" + strat.Group;
    //      }
    //      else
    //     {
    //          mailMessage.Body = messageBody + "<br/><br/>" + "<b>Create Date: &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>" + strat.CreateDate.ToString("MM/dd/yy") + "<br/>" + "<b>Updated: &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>" + strat.Updated + "<br/>" + "<b>Customer: &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>" + strat.Customer + "<br/>" + "<b>End Product: &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp</b>" + strat.EndProduct + "<br/>" + "<b>OSR: &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;</b>" + strat.OSR + "<br/>" + "<b>Principal: &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</b>" + strat.Principal + "<br/>" + "<b>Product: &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;</b>" + strat.Product + "<br/>" + "<b>Followup Date: &emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;</b>" + strat.FollowUpDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yy") + "<br/>" + "<b>Value: &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;</b>" + strat.Value + "<br/>" + "<b>Status: &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</b>" + strat.Status + "<br/>" + "<b>Next Action: &emsp;&emsp;&ensp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>" + strat.NextAction + "<br/>" + "<b>Latest Comments: &emsp;</b>" + strat.ManagerComment + "<br/>" + "<b>History: &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>" + strat.History + "<br/>" + "<b>Group: &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp</b>" + strat.Group;
    //      }
    // mailMessage.Body = messageBody + "<br/><br/>" + "<b>Create Date: </b>" + strat.CreateDate.ToString("MM/dd/yy") + "<br/>" + "<b>Updated: </b>" + strat.Updated + "<br/>" + "<b>Customer: </b>" + strat.Customer + "<br/>" + "<b>End Product: </b>" + strat.EndProduct + "<br/>" + "<b>OSR: </b>" + strat.OSR + "<br/>" + "<b>Principal: </b>" + strat.Principal + "<br/>" + "<b>Product: </b>" + strat.Product + "<br/>" + "<b>Followup Date: </b>" + strat.FollowUpDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yy") + "<br/>" + "<b>Value: </b>" + strat.Value + "<br/>" + "<b>Status: </b>" + strat.Status + "<br/>" + "<b>Next Action: </b>" + strat.NextAction + "<br/>" + "<b>Latest Comments: </b>" + strat.ManagerComment + "<br/>" + "<b>History: </b>" + strat.History + "<br/>" + "<b>Group: </b>" + strat.Group;
    //   mailMessage.To.Add(toAddress);
    //    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    //     smtp.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
    //      smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    //      System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
    //      NetworkCred.UserName = senderID;
    //      NetworkCred.Password = senderPassword;
    //      smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    //      smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
    //      smtp.Port = 25;
    //      smtp.Send(mailMessage);
```

Comment: You are mixing webforms and mvc code. That is not gonna work. Are you using webforms or mvc?

Comment: I am using mvc.

Comment: mvc does not have events. You code is for web forms, not mvc.

Comment: how would you do this in mvc?

Comment: I think I tried the mvc code and its working fine however is there anyway to send the email without knowing the user's password and just open the default mailing browser? I will post part of the code above.

Comment: You're way off there - that's going to run server side, which isn't what you want.  If you want a hyperlink that a user can click on, and it opens the default mail client on their machine, you simply need a link of the following format: `<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=Send Us an Email">Email Us</a>`.  This will set the *subject* of the email to "Send Us an Email".

Comment: Thank you! it is working the way I want it to now

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [mailto protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//aa767737(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)? This would mimic a situation where the user clicks an email address link. The default email client would open, and the fields would be filled automatically.

```
    createMail("some@email.com", "The Subject", "The Body");

    void createMail(string email, string subject, string body)
    {
        string theMailtoString = $"mailto:{email}?subject={subject}&body={body}";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(theMailtoString);
    }
```